# Reduction of the gravity gauge from various groups

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory, topology

As a gauge theory, the classic reduction for gravity is from the frame bundle to the Lorentz group,

\begin{equation}
GL(4) \to O(3,1)
\end{equation}

The associated configuration space of that reduction is the quotient

\begin{eqnarray}
GL(4) / O(3,1) &=& O(4) \times \mathbb{R}^{\frac{4 \times 4 + 4}{2} } / O(3) \times O(1) \times \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1} \\
&=& \mathbb{R}^7 \times O(4) / O(3) \times O(1)\\
&=& \mathbb{R}^7 \times \mathbb{R}P^3
\end{eqnarray}

This isn't extremely clear why it should be so, but first let's consider the Euclidian case, $GL(4) \to O(4)$ :

\begin{eqnarray}
GL(4) / O(4) &=& \mathbb{R}^{10}
\end{eqnarray}

This is the pretty obvious case of a metric tensor with ten components, or more accurately, a tetrad field with $16$ components reduced to $10$ from the $O(4)$ symmetry :

\begin{eqnarray}
g_E(X,Y) &=& \langle \theta(X), \theta(Y) \rangle\\
&=&  \theta^a(X) \theta_a(Y)
\end{eqnarray}

There is a classic formula to connect the Euclidian and Lorentzian metric via the use of a line element $\xi$ [or vector, if everything is orientable],

\begin{eqnarray}
g(X,Y) &=& g_E(X,Y) - 2 \frac{g_E(\xi, Y) g_E(\xi, X)}{g_E(\xi, \xi)}
\end{eqnarray}

This gives us a metric of the correct signature, with $\xi$ being a timelike vector field. This also hints at the origin of $\mathbb{R}P^3$, this is the direction field of $\xi$.

We can also get the two additional reductions $O(3,1) \to O(3)$ and $O(4) \to O(3)$, with

\begin{eqnarray}
O(3,1) / O(3) &=& \mathbb{R}^3 \times O(1)\\
O(4) / O(3) &=& S^3
\end{eqnarray}

we can use the following diagram :

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
GL(4) @>{\mathbb{R}^{10}}>> O(4)\\
@V{\mathbb{R}^{7} \times \mathbb{R}P^3}VV @V{S^3}VV \\
O(3,1) @>{\mathbb{R}^3 \times O(1)}>> O(3)
\end{CD}$$

The relation between the Euclidian and Lorentz metric do help a bit, but obviously, the Euclidian side of things has ten components for the metric and a direction field [which is about three components], so obviously there are some redundancies.

From what I can gather, the redundancies seem to stem from the fact that there is some $SO(3)$ gauge with respect to $\xi$ leaving the Lorentzian metric invariant.

Is this what's going on here? And also, are there any simpler ways to show that the metric tensor has this configuration space without all this?